# NullPointerException on getResource

Tags: java, file

I'm try to execute a file with SQL statements. Only the problem is with saving the file to a variable File it will produce a NullPointerException.

Here's the code:

```
 public DataOpladen(String dataFile) throws IOException {
    File file = null;
    try {
        file = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(dataFile).toURI());
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.dataSchrijvenNaarDatabase(file);
}
```

On this line I get the exception:

```
file = new File(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(dataFile).toURI());
```

The strange thing is sometimes it works, and sometimes it won't, so there is no line to get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IntelliJ is actively warning me that this particular invocation could result in a `NullPointerException` due to the fact that `getResource` will return `null` if it cannot find the specified resource.

Since you won't be able to do anything if you can't load in the required resource, a simple fix would be to do a null-check beforehand:

```
URL resource = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(dataFile);
if(resource != null) {
    file = new File(resource.toURI());
    // rest of program dealing with file here
}
```

Comment: This will still give me a nullpointer breaking my program. The problem is that the file is there in the resources of the project. So I don't get why he get's it?